# Phpmyadmin 413 request body too largge

Tags: php, docker, symfony, nginx, phpmyadmin

Im using docker and I have 3 services. An api service, a mysql service and phpmyadmin service. When I try to import an .sql file I get a 413 Request body too large error.

I have tried changing the nginx.conf settings in my phpmyadmin service, and the php.ini one with no luck. Basically everytime I bash into my container in order to change the configuration settings I seem to get stuck.

This is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  api:
    image: thecodingmachine/php:7.4-v3-apache-node12
    container_name: something
    environment:
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: project/public/
      PHP_INI_MEMORY_LIMIT: 512M
      PHP_INI_POST_MAX_SIZE: 256M
      PHP_INI_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 256M
      # Disable XDebug in production
      PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG: 0
      PHP_INI_ERROR_REPORTING: E_ALL
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__IDEKEY: VSCODE
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__CLI_COLOR: 1
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__REMOTE_PORT: 9000
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__SHOW_LOCAL_VARS: 1
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__REMOTE_AUTOSTART: 1
      # Symfony
      APP_ENV: dev
      APP_SECRET: something
      DATABASE_URL: something
      # STARTUP_COMMAND_1: composer install && bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
      # STARTUP_COMMAND_2: yarn install && yarn watch &
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/html:rw
    networks:
      - default
    restart: always
        
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: something
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: strong
      MYSQL_DATABASE: strong
      MYSQL_USER: strong
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: strong
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./services/mysql/utf8mb4.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/utf8mb4.cnf:ro
      - ./database:/database:rw
    restart: always
    
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.7
    container_name: project
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: local
      PMA_USER: some
      PMA_PASSWORD: some
    networks:
      - default

  
volumes:
  
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: local
```

Comment: Why not import the data using any other way, like: using the MySQL shell? And how is this related to Symfony or nginx?

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get my .sql file in my container. It is an nginx error and I am using symfony as my PHP framework.

Comment: How big is your SQL file? I feel like there's a lot of information missing here. I don't see how you're using nginx at all; the phpMyAdmin image uses Apache. Which `nginx.conf` file were you changing? Can you show us how you were trying to copy the SQL file in to the MySQL container — while we would want to help solve your import problem, it's usually more correct to import it programmatically in a Docker installation; minimizing the amount of manual work. Is it a file that must be imported each time the container is created or only once, since you link the mysql_data volume?

Comment: It's just a one time thing. Im trying to create the entities based off of this .sql file in symfony. Its not too big, I have 4 tables, its about 1 GB. I changed the ```nginx.conf``` inside my phpmyadmin container etc/nginx.conf. I tried to import programmatically via this command: ```docker exec -i mysql-container mysql -uuser -ppassword name_db < data.sql``` and it didn't give me any errors but I still couldn't see my tables inside phpmyadmin. I think I will just create my empty tables and generate the entities based off of these existing columns if that is possible.

Comment: A 1GB file is rather large to upload through a web interface, so I do recommend importing through the command line. However, the command you've used would require the `data.sql` file to be inside the container, so I am guessing the reason it didn't work is because the sql file is on your host machine. I'm not sure what the "docker-friendly" method would be, I suspect piping cat through netcat or something. Personally, I'd just copy the 1GB file to the container then remove it after import. By the way, some older phpMyAdmin versions did indeed use nginx not Apache; I missed that detail earlier.

Comment: How can I copy the ```data.sql``` file from my host machine into my container without creating a volume for it?

Comment: I *think* you can't COPY with docker-compose, only with a Dockerfile. But once the container is running, you can use `docker cp` on the MySQL container. Or I imagine you could put the .sql file in one of the volumes (mysql_data or database) just to get it in to the container, then you just have to know the path to provide to docker exec for the import. Another possible solution would be using `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`, which requires setting up a volume to copy in to the container, but any SQL file in that folder executes when the container is built.